# WordPress - Restrict categories to 1 level only

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm trying to make a community website in which users can create their own categories (for pages). I want to restrict their options.

I have six parent categories and I want the category-creation abilities to be limited to being a child-category of one of those six categories. Besides that, I don't want the user to be able te create any sub-categories that are NOT a child of one of my six parent-categories.

Just to be clear: The user can see every category there is. It's the creation of a new category I want to restrict to 1 level only!

I've been trying several things, but I can't seem to work this out. The internet wasn't much help either. Anyone out there any suggestions for me? I'm kinda stuck...

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-categories/

Comment: I have, but it only restricts the categories in which users can post. I still want the user to be able to create their own categories. But I want to 'force' them to do it as a child of one of the six categories I have already created.

Comment: Hm - that's not what the plugin docs say.  Can you chekc again?

Comment: I have installed the plugin and played around with it. But what happened was that the only categories shown to a user, were the categories I selected with the plugin. And that is NOT what I want. They should be able to see EVERY category. The only restriction is the level in which they can CREATE their own categories. Thanks for thinking along with me, though!

Answer (score -1):

When you create texonomy 
'hierarchical' => true, make it false 
This will allow you to add only parent category no child category will created.

Comment: But I do want there to be a hierarchy. I just want that hiërarchy to be limited to a certain level. The top levels are already created and fixed. I want to force the users to choose one of those categories as parents, when they create their own category. And I do want them to be able to create their own categories!